# Response from Servers... Connection to http://192.168.3.11:3000 refused

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

Ruby version 2.2.4
Rails version 5.0.0.1
Hello People,

I have programmed an android app, which can take profile pictures from a user. Now I want to upload these profile picture to my Ruby on Rail server. However the upload doesn't work. I receive the Error message:

```
Response from Servers org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.3.11:3000 refused
```

Here is the host-adress I use in my android-app. I use  my local ip-adress so this part should be correct.

```
public class Config {
    // File upload url (replace the ip with your server address)
  //  public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.3.11:3000/AndroidFileUpload/fileUpload.php";
    public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.3.11:3000/";
    // Directory name to store captured images and videos
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "android_upload";
}
```

And this is my ruby on rails app:
**items_controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
    send_data(item.file_contents,
              type: @item.content_type,
              filename: @item.filename)
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render :show, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      render :show, status: :ok, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :picture)
    end
end
```

**models/item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

**uploaders/picture_uploader.rb**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
   def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
   end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :items
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Serve websocket cable requests in-process
  # mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'

end
```

UPDATE: I added a post in routes.db: post  to: 'items' and start the RoR Server with rails s -b 192.168.3.11. Now I get following error,

```
 app/controllers/items_controller.rb:55:in `item_params'
    app/controllers/items_controller.rb:21:in `create'
    Started POST "/items" for 192.168.3.7 at 2016-09-11 01:12:21 +0900
    Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x5737110 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Clemens/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20160911-2
    8624-1vjbftr.jpg>, @original_filename="IMG_20160911_010525.jpg", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; na
    me=\"image\"; filename=\"IMG_20160911_010525.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}
    Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:55:in `item_params'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

After this error message I commented parameters out but still the same error:

```
   def item_params
      #######################params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :picture)
      params.permit(:picture)
```

Comment: When you start your Rails App, try `rails s -b 192.168.3.11` to bind to the local network ip instead of the loopback.

Comment: Thanks!! Now one step closer to finish. It tries now to send the image. However I receive now from server: Error occurred! Http Status Code: 404

Comment: ruby on rails console says: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/")  How can I implement this?

Comment: You would need a root path. However, your item controller is where you would want to post to. Change the URL in your Config class to http://192.168.3.11/item

Comment: ok I changed to 192.168.3.11/items and in routes.rb I added post to: 'items' . Now I get this error:  ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:54:in `item_params'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:21:in `create'

Comment: The parameters (form data) that your passing aren't correct then.

Comment: OK I just send an Image from android: entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile)); And in Ruby on Rails I changed to params.require(:item).permit(:picture) .  But I still get the same error

Comment: It is expecting { item: { picture: <picturestuff> }} to be posted.

Comment: so how do I then change the code?

Comment: You have now gotten the rails side working, but your android side needs some work. To temp override this, you could have something like this in your create action `@item = Item.new` `@item.picture = params[:image]` but you would still be missing the name and description.

Comment: I finally can upload the file when I just leave it by params.require(:item).permit(picture) . It shows me Server Response Ok 201. However now I dont know how I can see the image in ruby on rails. I have no Idea..